# Implement One-To-Many bi-directional relationship in app engine Java

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

i want to implement bi-directional One-To-Many relationship in my app engine application. I have two entities - entity A (parent) and entity B(child).

Parent :

```
    @Entity
    public class A implements Serializable {

        @Id
        private String aId;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "objA", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        List<B> bList;

        getter().........setter()
   }
```

Child :

```
      @Entity
      public class B implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Key bId;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private A parentA;

            getter().........setter()
      }
```

Here,at first i persist object of class A and at that time i don't set its `bList` property. After that i create object of B and update `setbList()` of A which will automatically persist object of type B in datastore (as here i have set `cascade=CascadeType.ALL`).Now i want to access A from B objects.(parent from child) in my endpoint class which i am using in my android client. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a reference to A in your B class

```
private A parentA;

parentA = //whatever you use when you update setbList()
```

Good luck!

Comment: hey i edited my code. you can see it. I have written as you said but when i try to set value of parentA, it throws `JsonMappingException` for recursion.

Comment: Could you post Class B?

Comment: `JsonMappingException` has nothing to do with the datastore (or persistence in general). It is generated by your serialization frameworks because there is a circular reference between object A <-> B.

Comment: @Roy..i have edited my code.You can check there for my class B.

Comment: @MichaelakoTecourt..I know its just because of circular reference between A<->B..so what should i do to make it work?